# Jquery how to replace img to another img by click

Tags: html, jquery, replace

I have a question.

I have some code in html page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img-1").click(function() {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $(".click-img").attr('src', imgsrc);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img-2").click(function() {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $(".click-img").attr('src', imgsrc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/mults_dobicha_ognya.gif" id="img-1"></td>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/animaciya.gif" id="img-2"></td>
  </tr>
</div>

<div>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/risunki_svecha.gif" class="click-img" id="select-1"></td>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/risunki_svecha.gif" class="click-img" id="select-2"></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

And how can I change img by replace. For example: i click to image with id="img-1" then click image with id="select-1". And image  id="img-1" replaced by id="select-1" ?

My Jquery is not working and i can't understand how solve this problem. So do you have some better solution?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_, _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: _"for example i click "img-1" then click "select-1""_ - There's nothing in your script that would do something after clicking on one of the "select"s

Comment: @Andreas now is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you were looking for but it can always give you an idea

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var srcCopy = '';
  
  $(".defaultImg").click(function() {
    srcCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  });
  
   $(".click-img").click(function() {
      if( srcCopy ){
        $(this).attr('src', srcCopy);
        srcCopy = '';
      }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/mults_dobicha_ognya.gif" id="img-1"class="defaultImg" ></td>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/animaciya.gif" id="img-2" class="defaultImg" ></td>
  </tr>
</div>

<div>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/risunki_svecha.gif" class="click-img" id="select-1"></td>
    <td><img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/avatarka/100na100/risunki_svecha.gif" class="click-img" id="select-2"></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```